# Ruby Genetic Algorithm never reaching peak

Tags: ruby, genetic-algorithm

I'm a beginner in Ruby writing a very simple program to mimic genetics, but the output fitness always stays around 15-24, roughly. Shouldn't this program eventually reach a fitness of 32 and then output so?

**Edited code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Animal
  attr_reader :genes

  def initialize (genes=[])
    @genes = genes
  end

  def random_chromosome
    @genes = Array.new(32).collect {|x| rand 2}
    self
  end

  def calc_fitness
    @genes.inject(0){|i, v| next i + v if v == 1; i}
  end

  def mutate
   2.times { @genes[rand 32] = rand 2}
  end

  def mate(other)
    @genes = (@genes[0...16] + other.genes[0...16])
    mutate
    self
  end

  def is_spartan?
    @genes == (Array.new.fill 1)
  end
end

class Generation
  attr_reader :animals

  def initialize (animals=[], gen_size = 10)
    @animals = animals
    @gen_size = gen_size
  end
  def seed
    @animals = Array.new(@gen_size).collect {Animal.new.random_chromosome}
  end
  def mate
    @animals = [].tap {|a|
        @gen_size.times{ 
            a << @animals[rand @gen_size].mate(@animals[rand @gen_size])
          }
        }
  end
  def alphas
    @animals.sort! {|a, b| b.calc_fitness <=> a.calc_fitness}.first(@gen_size)
  end
  def include_spartans?
    @animals.include? Array.new(32).fill 1  #perfect genes
  end
  def output
    @animals.each {|an| print "#{an.genes.join}: #{an.calc_fitness}\n"}
  end
end

NUM_OFFSPRING = 10
gen = Generation.new
gen.seed

i = 0
loop do
  i += 1
  if gen.include_spartans? #end if there are any perfect genes
    puts "Members have reached spartan status!"
    break
  end

  puts "*** ALPHAS FROM GENERATION: #{i}***" 
  gen.mate
  gen.alphas
  gen.output
  sleep(0.2)
    end
```

**Sample Output**

*** ALPHAS FROM GENERATION: 1***

11101101011111101001010110101101: 21
10111111111100000110000101011001: 18
11101111110110111100001100000001: 18
11000101101111010110000111011001: 18
11101111110110111100001100000001: 18
10111111111100000110000101011001: 18
11000101101111010110000111011001: 18
11000011010000011001101111101101: 17
01100001110110011000101111110000: 16
10001010111110001100001101000001: 14

*** ALPHAS FROM GENERATION: 2***

11101111110110101110111111010011: 24
01100001110110011110111111011110: 21
11000101101111011100001101000001: 16
10001010111110000110000111011001: 16
11000101101111011100001101000001: 16
10111111010100001000001101100001: 15
10111111010100001000001101100001: 15
10111111010100001000001101100001: 15
10111111010100001000001101100001: 15
10111111010100001000001101100001: 15

*** ALPHAS FROM GENERATION: 3***

11101111111110101011111111000000: 22
11101111111110101011111111000000: 22
10111111110000001110011111011010: 20
10111111110000001110011111011010: 20
10111111110000001110011111011010: 20
11000101101111011000101011111000: 18
11000101101111011000101011111000: 18
11000101101111011000101011111000: 18
11000101101111011000101011111000: 18
01100001110100011011111101010000: 16

Comment: Care to share what the downvote is for?

Comment: You are writing mostly functional code in object oriented ruby. I would suggest structuring methods into an `Animal` object, this might make it easier to see what you want to achieve.

Comment: Without seeing your output it is kind of hard to guess what you would expect. From my understanding of genetic programming you seem to lack the selection step. Your method of mating just takes half the chromosomes of some ancestor and combines them with half the chromosomes of another. Even if you sort the offspring this will not improve your generation if it always operates on a generation size of 10. Try increasing `NUM_OFFSPRING` in order improve the generations, that way there will be some individuals that are refused the mating. And: add your output.

Comment: Moreover you might like to choose the chromosomes randomly. At the moment you will always use the first half of the chromosomes to create the next generation. The second part of the chromosomes will help your fitness, but they will not influence the result of the `mate`.

Comment: Edited for object oriented-ness, but increasing `NUM_OFFSPRING` doesn't seem to do much? Also could you explain your third comment better?

Comment: Thanks for the objects, that makes talking about it a lot easier. I do understand that increasing `@gen_size` will not help much in the current implementation. That is because you always select the whole generation in your `alphas`-method, so there is no actual selection of the 'good' individuals to mate. Your `@gen_size` should be larger than your `@alpha_size` if you get what I mean.

Comment: The third point was about choosing the mating chromosomes randomly. At the moment your 'fitness' is defined as the number of ones in all the chromosomes, but the second half (16..31) never get any influence on the `mate` function. So an individual all ones in the second half and 7 ones in the first one will score as incredibly 'fit', but it will actually turn out to be a substandard 'mate'. I hope you can see what I mean now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patru put you on the right track. It's a handful of issues resolved here: https://gist.github.com/matt-glover/9700810

The original code does not use `NUM_OFFSPRING`. Even if it did it also pulls 10 animals back as alphas (or tries to anyway) so `NUM_OFFSPRING` really should be bigger to see the alpha selection show any impact.

The original code sorts the animals in place to find alphas but does not actually keep the top 10. Instead it returns the top 10 from the method call but stores the full sorted `@animals` array.

Mating needs to produce a new `Animal` otherwise the same animal can be selected over and over again in the mating stage. The original code keeps the results only from the last mating attempt stored in the first animal in the mating pair. This eventually eliminates the animal pool to a single animal showing up multiple times in the animals list and only reflecting the genes from the last mating attempt that iteration.

Finally the `include_spartans?` check either needs to map the genes as done in the example or call through to each animal and perform the check there. The old code was checking an animal instance against an array of ones.

Comment: Thank you! Genetics is a very fine art, it seems.